# How to @Inject a set of modules into a unit test with @ProvidesIntoSet annotation

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, dependency-injection, guice, mockk

I am trying to unit test the following. I have a class as below -

```
@Singleton
class A @Inject constructor(
  private val dependency1,
  private val dependency2
) {

  @Inject(optional = true)
  val handlersSet: Set<IHandlers>? = null
  ....
}
```

This is how it is injected in the main application

```
class Modules : AbstractModule() {

    @ProvidesIntoSet
    @Inject
    fun getSomeHandler(
        impl: SomeHandler
    ): IHandlers {
        return impl
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far in my unit test, where it is not working. `handlersSet` is always null. I want to write test cases for handlersSet which are injected by Guice for this class A, but it is always getting set to `null`. I tried various things, and below is what I have right now. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
class ATest {
    private val dependency1 = mockk<Dependency1>(relaxed = true)
    private val dependency2 = mockk<Dependency2>(relaxed = true)
    private val objectUnderTest = A(dependency1, dependency2)

    protected var injector: Injector = Guice.createInjector(object : AbstractModule() {
        override fun configure() {
            install(Modules())
        }
    })

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        injector.injectMembers(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun `some test`() {}
}
```